# Unsure of correct BEM style syntax

Tags: html, css, syntax, naming-conventions, bem

Let's say I have a product within a collection. Is it appropriate to call the product "feature-collection__product" so it's still an element within the block of "feature-collection" or call it "feature-collection-product" so it becomes it's own block, as it has other elements within it, or something different.

```
<div class="feature-collection">

    <div class="feature-collection__product">
        <h2 class="feature-collection__product-title"></h2>
        <h2 class="feature-collection__product-price"></h2>     
    </div>

</div>
```

**OR**

```
<div class="feature-collection">

    <div class="feature-collection-product">
        <h2 class="feature-collection-product__title"></h2>
        <h2 class="feature-collection-product__price"></h2>     
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the correct answer is both:

```
<div class="feature-collection">
    <div class="feature-collection__product product">
        <h2 class="product__title"></h2>
        <h2 class="product__price"></h2>     
    </div>
</div>
```

The situation when you have different entities on the same DOM node is called mix. In this case it's reasonable to have independent block **product** and also an element of **feature-collection** to set some styling for production inside feature-collection.

For more info about mixes please take a look at https://en.bem.info/methodology/key-concepts/#mix and https://en.bem.info/methodology/faq/#mixes